# Change View to another View within a Storyboard and share data to the new view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uistoryboard, uidatepicker

Got a question, I'm trying to return to a previous view and share some data over to the frame I'm returning to.  The data will be date and time and I would like to send this to a textField.

For example I'm calling the date *returneddate and the textField I'm calling *dateTime. The views are call *PickDateTime and SubmitEventsP2.

If you need more information just ask me and I'll add it if I can to make it easier for you to help me.

I'm using Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. its pretty simple.. you should use a delegate... if i understood correctly, you are on a secondary view and when you return to the main view you wish to send the data from the second view back to the main view, right?

so, in your second view, in the .h file, on top of interface, you will declare the delegate with:

```
@class nameOfTheViewController;

@protocol nameOfTheViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)methodNameOfDelegateReturning:(NSString *)string otherString:(NSString *)string2;
@end
```

And in your interface, still in the .h, you will create a reference of this delegate like:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) id <nameOfTheViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

after that, in your .m of nameOfTheViewController you will do:

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

After you created you delegate in the nameOfTheViewController file, you will call the delegate method you just created exactly where and when you want to return to the previous view, filling it with the parameters you want to pass back... and of course, in your mainViewController, right in your didPrepareForSegue method, you will create a instance of the nameOfTheViewController class and set its delegate proeprty to self... for this to be possible, in your mainViewController .h you must conform to the nameOfTheViewControllerDelegate protocol.

Comment: Ok, I've done the above but I'm not sure how to go about changing the view back, I forgot to mention I've only just recently started xcode development with not much knowledge of anything else either.

Comment: Well, you should then read in some tutorials on how to implement a delegate... i pratically said everything that is needed... just don't forget to accept the answer if it is right..!!